# Is the class of Heyting algebras originating from directed graphs a variety?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, graph-theory, universal-algebra

The category **RefGph** of [reflexive directed graphs](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflexive+graph)
is the functor category $\hat{∆}_1=\mbox{Fun}(∆^◦_1,$**Set**), where $∆_1$ is 
the [simplex category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplex+category) truncated at level 1.

[Hence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heyting+category) the poset Sub(X) of subobjects of such a graph X is a [Heyting algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heyting+algebra).

I am interested in the category $K_1$, whose objects are the Heyting algebras, which are isomorphic to those of the form Sub(X) for some reflexive directed graph $X$.

As F. Dorais [explains](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231492/heyting-algebras-originating-from-directed-graphs), these algebras can be described as subalgebras of  powers of the Heyting algebra $\Omega_1$, whose underlyinig set consists of the five elements $$|\Omega_1|=\{0, s,t,s\vee t,1\}.$$ Its lattice operations are given by the tables
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc} 
\wedge & 0 & s     & t     & s\vee t      & 1  \\\hline
0       & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
s           & 0 & s     & 0 & s     & s      \\
t            & 0 & 0 & t     & t     & t      \\
s\vee t  & 0 & s     & t     & s\vee t     & s\vee t       \\
1       & 0 & s     & t     & s\vee t     & 1   \\
\end{array}\qquad\qquad 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc} 
\vee      & 0 & s     & t     & s\vee t      & 1  \\\hline
0      & 0 & s     & t     & s\vee t      & 1   \\
s           & s     & s     & s\vee t     & s\vee t      & 1   \\
t           & t     & s\vee t      & t    & s\vee t      & 1   \\
s\vee t           & s\vee t     & s\vee t      & s\vee t    & s\vee t      & 1   \\
1       & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1   \\
\end{array}$$

So its underlying poset has the Hasse-diagram

[image: Hasse-digaram of $\Omega_1$]

Its (relative) pseudocomplement is given by the table

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc} 
\Rightarrow & 0 & s        & t       & s\vee t      & 1  \\\hline
0              & 1  & 1  & 1   & 1  & 1  \\
s                  & t     & 1   & t       & 1  & 1  \\
t                  & s     & s       & 1   & 1  & 1 \\
s\vee t         & 0 & s       & t       & 1  & 1  \\
1              & 0 & s       & t      & s\vee t      & 1  \\
\end{array}\qquad\qquad 
\begin{array}{c|c} 
\neg & \\\hline
0  &          1   \\
s      &          t      \\
t      &          s      \\
s\vee t       &          0  \\
1  &          0  \\
\end{array}
$$

Hence my question:

Is $K_1$ a variety of algebras? (finitary algebraic category)

Can you give some references to relevant papers?

Comment: As I mentioned in my earlier answer, since every $\operatorname{Sub}(X)$ is complete, $K_1$ isn't closed under subalgebras so it is not a variety.